# can android phone power a peripheral via usb?

Tags: usb, android

The 5V micro usb port on the android phone allows the phone to be charged from the mains and programmed.  Is it possible that a usb connection to the phone can power a peripheral?

ie I want to power a PIC microprocessor and want its power to come from the phone rather than a separate power supply

Comment: The answer is "Theoretically yes. *Your* phone? Ask the manufacturer.".

Answer (score 2):

Powering a peripheral from an android device depends on the hardware and the firmware of the device in question. Android the OS is not what enables it. Some devices can provide a USB-On-The-Go full power connection with stock firmware. Some need an app to enable it. Some need a firmware update. Others can only do usb data, with a power injection cable. Some of those also need an app or firmware change. Finally, some cannot at all. If yours has the hardware but no firmware capable of activating it, it can't be done without creating drivers from scratch. Some have the hardware, but its physically scrippled on the pcb.

Oh, and some might need special resistor pairs on the usb port data or id pin to activate the power mode.

So, maybe.

Comment: thanks for comments.  I think it might be easier to just power the PIC from the same power supply as powering phone and just demand phone is plugged in for it to work

Answer (score 1):

If the phone has [USB On-The-Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), you can draw power from the USB port in host mode. How much current you're able to pull depends on the phone.